# SO_TIMESTAMPING: Overhead?

Tags: linux, timestamps

I use `SO_TIMESTAMPING` with `SOF_TIMESTAMPING_RX_SOFTWARE` to generate software timestamps for TCP and UDP streams.

Is it known what's the overhead for using this flag? Does the throughput or the latency get significantly worse?

Thanks a lot

Comment: what throughput and latency bounds are we talking when we are saying "significantly"? It makes a difference whether we're talking about something coming out of a DSL line in time for a multiplayer online game or whether we're saturating SFP28 at 25 Gb/s and are handling timing-critical radio frontend data.